# Codex Function Problems When There is an Apostrophe in the Category Name

Tags: breadcrumb, htmlspecialchars-decode

I'm working on a site, largely managed by categories.  Two of the categories have apostrophes in them... ex. "Joe's Place" and "Tina's Lounge".  (Actual titles changed, these are examples...)  The category slugs are "joes-place" and "tinas-lounge".

The customer asked for a breadcrumb on the site... Unfortunately the breadcrumb call fails whenever the category has an apostrophe in its name.  The failure occurs at the call to get_cat_ID.  Oh, and when the breadcrumb fails, the whole page fails.  Here is a fragment of my breadcrumb code...

```
if ( is_category() )
        {
            // single_cat_title() Displays or returns the page title if a category
            // or tag archive is queried. 
            $catTitle = single_cat_title( "", false );   
            echo '<!-- $catTitle:'.$catTitle." -->";  // troubleshooting line... 
            $cat = get_cat_ID( $catTitle );
            echo '<!-- $cat: '.$cat."-->";   // troubleshooting line
            echo "<li>  ". get_category_parents_custom( $cat, TRUE, ' &raquo; ' ) ."</li>";
        }
```

get_cat_ID simply returns a `0`.  Uh-oh... when I look close at my troubleshooting code, I can see that $catTitle returns `Joe&#8217;s Place`

Ouch.. Its really not clear on exactly what format is required where the apostrophe is concerned. When I dig further and further in codex core, I can see get_cat_ID calls a function `get_term_by()` that warns "$value is not HTML-escaped for the 'name' $field. You must do it yourself, if required."  I'm assuming that's my issue.  but, what does it mean to "HTML-Escape" a string?

I tried `$catTitle2 = htmlspecialchars_decode($catTitle);` no go there.
I tried `$catTitle2 = esc_html($catTitle);` no go there.
In both of those previous functions, the string never changes a bit.

I tried manually introducing the string "Joe's Place" to the call, and WOW, that totally worked.

In the meantime I will do a simple string replace function, but that seems like such a hack.

Is there a php or wordpress function that will convert the string `&#8217;` back to a simple apostrophe?  What is the right way to fix this problem?

Update:
I stumbled upon [this posting:](http://nickjohnson.com/b/wordpress-apostrophe-vs-right-single-quote)  My quick fix consists of a bit of code suggested there with a small modification:

```
     $catTitleCorrected = html_entity_decode(str_replace("&#8217;","'",$catTitle));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. May it will help you.

[ent2ncr](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/ent2ncr)

Converts named entities into numbered entities.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that your final aim is obtain the current category id to use in a `get_category_parents_custom` function and you are using `single_cat_title` to get current cat name an pass it to `get_cat_ID` to get current category id.

I think you are making your life harder, because you can use [`get_queried_object_id`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_queried_object_id/) to get the current category id when `is_category()` is true, or you can access the category object using [`get_queried_object`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) and then make use of category ID and name form that object. Example code:

```
if ( is_category() ) {
  $cat = get_queried_object();
  // if you also need category name uncomment next line
  // $catTitle = $cat->name;
  echo "<li>  " . get_category_parents_custom( $cat->term_id, TRUE, ' &raquo; ' ) . "</li>";
}
```